# Swift i want to check the data entered by user

Tags: swift

I'm new to coding on Swift and I'm having a problem with a code. I want to verify the data entered by the user.

IngredientDetailView contains a form to add or modify an ingredient. In this view I want to control the data entered by the user. So the ingredients have a unique name.

My problem
When I modify the name of an existing ingredient with a name of another ingredient, my control does not work.

IngredientListView contains the list of existing ingredients that can be modified.

Thanks in advance for reading and helping.

```
struct IngredientDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State var ingredientItemData : Ingredient
    @EnvironmentObject var ingredientsVM: IngredientModel
    // To display the message that an ingredient already exists
    @State private var showingAlertIngredientExist = false
    let metrics: [String] = [
        "Unité", "kg", "g", "l", "ml"
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            TextField("Ingredient name", text: $ingredientItemData.nom)
            Text("Metric").bold()
            Picker(selection: $ingredientItemData.metric, label: Text("Metric"), content: {
                ForEach(metrics, id: \.self){ item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }).pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                Button("Cancel"){
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                Button("Ok"){
                    //If the id already exists
                    if ingredientsVM.ingredients.contains(where: {$0.id == ingredientItemData.id}){
                        // If the name you entered already exists
                        if ingredientsVM.ingredients.contains(where: {$0.nom.lowercased() == ingredientItemData.nom.lowercased()}){
                            // We get the index of the element we are working on
                            let i = ingredientsVM.ingredients.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == ingredientItemData.id})
                            // We check if the name has not changed if the ingredient has not been modified
                            if ingredientsVM.ingredients[i!].nom == ingredientItemData.nom {
                                dismiss()
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // The name you want to modify already exists
                                showingAlertIngredientExist.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            // We save and save in the application
                            ingredientsVM.add(ing: ingredientItemData)
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    } else{
                        // No ID so we check if the name entered by the user already exists
                        if ingredientsVM.ingredients.contains(where: {$0.nom.lowercased() == ingredientItemData.nom.lowercased()}){
                            // The name you want to modify already exists
                            showingAlertIngredientExist.toggle()
                        }
                        else{
                            // We save and save in the application
                            ingredientsVM.add(ing: ingredientItemData)
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
}
                .alert(isPresented: $showingAlertIngredientExist){
                    Alert(title: Text("Ingredient already present"), message: Text("An ingredient already exists with this name !"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

struct IngredientDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IngredientDetailView(ingredientItemData: Ingredient())
            .environmentObject(IngredientModel())
    }
}

struct IngredientListView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    
    @State private var sheetIsPresented = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var ingredientVM: IngredientModel
        
    func getIndex(item: Ingredient) -> Int{
        return ingredientVM.ingredients.firstIndex{(item1) -> Bool in
            return item.id == item1.id
        } ?? 0
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            List{
                ForEach(ingredientVM.ingredients){ item in
                    NavigationLink{
                        IngredientDetailView(ingredientItemData: item)
                    }label: {
                        Text(item.nom)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete{ indexSet in
                    // Temporaire. Fonction à mettre dans le model
                    ingredientVM.ingredients.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                    ingredientVM.saveData()
                }
            }.navigationTitle("IngredientListView")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                    Button{
                        sheetIsPresented.toggle()
                    }label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $sheetIsPresented){
                NavigationStack{
                    IngredientDetailView(ingredientItemData: Ingredient())
                }
                .presentationDetents([.large,.medium,.fraction(0.75)])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct IngredientListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        IngredientListView()
            .environmentObject(IngredientModel())
    }
}

class IngredientModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var ingredients : [Ingredient] = []
    let saveKey = "Ingredients"
    
    init(){
        loadData()
    }
    
    func add(ing: Ingredient){
        if ing.id == nil{
            var newIngredient = ing
            newIngredient.id = UUID().uuidString
            ingredients.append(newIngredient)
        }else{
            if let index = ingredients.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == ing.id}){
                ingredients[index] = ing
            }
        }
        saveData()
    }
    
    func loadData(){
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: saveKey){
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Ingredient].self, from: data){
                ingredients = decoded
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveData(){
        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(ingredients) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: saveKey)
        }
    }
}

class Ingredient: Identifiable, Codable{
    var id: String?
    var nom = ""
    var metric = ""
    
    init (){
        
    }
    
    init(id: String, nom: String, metric: String){
        self.id = id
        self.nom = nom
        self.metric = metric
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `ingredientItemData` get created and get an id?

Comment: Hello, I just updated with all the view code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You said "before the data is saved with my backup method the data is already saved without going through the function." -- what is the backup method. What does already saved mean? Going through what function (backup?).  If you are checking `id`, why do you also need to check `name`.  And we still don't know how the data got ids -- and if they are unique

Comment: Actually it was not clear. I added all my code. Yes, I want the ingredients to have a unique name. And that's why I'm going to do a name check and I'm using the ID which is also unique for each ingredient.

Comment: Ok, you said "my control does not work" -- what does it do exactly and what did you want it to do?

Comment: I want to check that it is not possible to enter a name of an existing ingredient when editing another ingredient. This is to avoid duplication and user errors.

Currently, it is possible to modify the name of an ingredient with that of an existing ingredient. Something I don't want.

Ask me if you need more clarification